# jstree to check uncheck only if clicked on checkbox not on label

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have rendered a tree view using jsTree, how can I check/uncheck node only if clicked on checkbox icon and not on label of node?

Comment: Show us what have you tried yet?

Comment: I tried to set check box properties but still it is check/uncheck if I select node label

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found answer to my own question
after setting following properties it behaves as expected.

```
        $('#testTree').jstree({ 
    core: {
      data: getData, 
      check_callback: false
    }, 
    checkbox: {       
      three_state : false, 
      whole_node : false,//Used to check/uncheck node only if clicked on checkbox icon, and not on the whole node including label
      tie_selection : false
    },
    plugins: ['checkbox']
})
```

Comment: It works! And remember to replace the "select_node.jstree" and "deselect_node.jstree" events with "check_node.jstree" or "uncheck_node.jstree" events.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is just the removal of "wholerow" in the jstree options bit:

So, from

```
"plugins": ["wholerow", "checkbox"],
```

to:

```
"plugins": ["checkbox"],
```

So, the whole jstree config looks like:

```
$('#testTree').jstree({
    "core": {
        "themes": {
        "theme": "default",
        "dots": false,
        "icons": false
        },
        "data": @Html.Raw(ViewBag.Menu)
    },
    "checkbox": {
        "keep_selected_style": false,
    },
    "plugins": ["checkbox"],
});
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. The "wholerow" plugin only renders the hover box on the entire row. It has nothing to do with the checkbox plugin.